# Are there any Epson dot matrix printers that support Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I need to buy a new Epson dot matrix printer that supports Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Windows 7 Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?type=Hardware&s=Epson%20dot%20matrix) show's 32 Epson dot matrix printers compatible with Windows 7 64-bit edition.

Answer (score 0):

The Epson DLQ 3500 does, and very well, I've just set two up.